# Bootstrap container fluid elements loses layout inside drop down menu with position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customise Bootstrap 4 navbar and its contents...my task is to add more nav items on drop down menu. the problems comes when i wrap container fluid elements in drop down items with its default CSS style (position absolute) the container fluid elements loses layout on large screen size .

I will be grateful for any help you can provide to fix my code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .col-lg-3 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    max-width: 18%;
  }
  
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

</style>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      
      
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-3 ">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">One Page</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Construction</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Landing page</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-3 ">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Personal</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Transportation</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Education</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Corperate</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a></li>
           </ul>
           </div>


           <div class="col-lg-3 ">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
               <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Health</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Admin</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agency</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
           </ul>
           </div>
           
           
           
            <div class="col-lg-3">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Movies</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sport & Entertainement</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nature</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Photography</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resaurant</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Medical</a></li>
           </ul>
           </div>
           
           
            <div class="col-lg-3">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Movies</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sport & Entertainement</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nature</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Photography</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resaurant</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Medical</a></li>
           </ul>
           </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write media query to handle it or add a extra class to dropdown as I did.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .col-lg-3 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    max-width: 18%;
  }
  
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.flex-1{
  flex:1;
  width: 100%;
}

</style>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto flex-1">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      
      
      <li class="nav-item dropdown flex-1">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-3 ">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">One Page</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Construction</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Landing page</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-3 ">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Personal</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Transportation</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Education</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Corperate</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a></li>
           </ul>
           </div>


           <div class="col-lg-3 ">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
               <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Health</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Admin</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agency</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
           </ul>
           </div>
           
           
           
            <div class="col-lg-3">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Movies</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sport & Entertainement</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nature</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Photography</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resaurant</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Medical</a></li>
           </ul>
           </div>
           
           
            <div class="col-lg-3">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Movies</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sport & Entertainement</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nature</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Photography</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resaurant</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Medical</a></li>
           </ul>
           </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```